# Meteor js - "uncaught There can only be one platform" error

Tags: meteor, angular2-routing, angular-meteor

I'm following along with this tutorial with Meteor and Angular 2 and I must've screwed up along the way or their tutorial is incorrect.  I've double checked my files and everything seems to match the tutorial.  I've also tried meteor reset, but can't figure out what causes this error. I'm too much of a newb at Meteor and Angular2 to really decipher what's wrong.  I've looked at the lines listed in the error and they seem to match the tutorial.  Anyone know what causes this "one platform" error?

I was able to follow successfully until step 5: 
http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/routing-and-multiple-views

```
ERROR:
application_ref.js:36Uncaught There can be only one platform. Destroy the previous one to create a new one.
createPlatform @ application_ref.js:36
MeteorApp.bootstrap @ meteor_app.js:22
bootstrap @ bootstrap.js:9
meteorInstall.client.app.js @ app.ts:22
fileEvaluate @ install.js:141
require @ install.js:75
(anonymous function) @ parties.ts:3
```

Answer (score 0):

Posted a question on the angular-meteor forum and was able to rectify the issue.  https://forums.meteor.com/t/angular-meteor-angular2-tutorial-zip-and-site-dont-match-which-is-correct/23943/3

Solved by updating to this package: https://github.com/cesargalindo/socially-step05